# Can we define the set of functions mapping non-empty set X to set Y as follows?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is it acceptable in a rigorous proof to define the set $F$ of unary functions mapping elements of a non-empty set $X$ to elements of a set $Y$ as follows?

$~~~~~~\forall f: [f \in F \iff \forall a: [a\in X \implies f(a)\in Y]]$

Comment: If we don't already know what these functions are, then what does the notation $f(a)$ mean in this definition? What is the universe of possible $f$s in the $\forall f$ notation?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function.

It is easy to forget that $f(x)$ is not a function, $f$ is the function object. $f(x)$ is a element in $Y$.

In set theory, function $f$ is usually defined as a **relation** from a set of inputs to a set of possible outputs where **each input is related to exactly one output.**

Some people, also define **relations** in terms of function. It doesn't matter how you choose to define it.

However you choose to define it, $f$ is a subset of $X \times Y$, so set of functions is a subset of **powerset** of $X \times Y$.

So your definition should be like

$$\forall f \in \mathcal{P}(X \times Y) : [f \in F \iff [\forall a \in X, \exists b, c  \in Y : [(a, b) \in f \land (a, c) \in f \implies b = c]]]$$

I hope it is clear. and I'm not wrong!

The above thing is saying like... for every relation "$f$" in $\mathcal{P} (X \times Y)$, $f$ belongs to set of all functions $F$, iff relation $f$ is a function.

Comment: Are you equating a function with its graph?

Comment: It is a visual way to think. but we don't have graph in our language yet. we can't define using graphs.. I edited the answer.

Comment: By the graph of a function, I meant $\{(a,b) \in X\times Y | F(a,b)\}$ for some predicate $F$. So, you would have $f(a)=b \iff a\in X \land b\in Y \land F(a,b)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Here, what is $F(a, b)$? Here we are trying to is define $F$. but according to your definition, $f$ is a function $\iff f \in F$. you see this circular logic? 

 A function is a bipartite graph from $X$ to $Y$ such that degree of all vertices in $X$ is 1. How is the definition restricting degree of  all vertices in $X$ to 1?

Comment: and Is $F$ a predicate or a set of functions?